# Substring from String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the code to find out substring from string in `Swift`, Please help !

My codes to find substring `http://corbpl.com/groupinfo.php?show=95` is :-

```
var aString: String = "href=http://www.corpbpl.com/groupinfo.php?show=95 onmousedown=uaction(this,{up:'90de%=%Nofi7rO6B&l=8upb1p&E%=6&ex=jXTDh5zYQLa9&});"

var hashtag: NSRange = aString.rangeOfString("http://")

var word: NSRange = 
aString.substringFromIndex(aString.startIndex.advancedBy(hashtag.location))
```

Comment: Show what you've tried in Swift.

Comment: yes i am done now tell

Answer (score 3):

You should keep your original Objective-C code to tell what you want to do.
(I mean your post should contain both the original code, and what you have done till now.)

And your input String should be like this as a String literal:

```
var aString = "href=\"http://www.corpbpl.com/groupinfo.php?show=95\" onmousedown=\"uaction(this,{up:'90de%=%Nofi7rO6B&l=8upb1p&E%=6&ex=jXTDh5zYQLa9&})\""
```

In Swift 2:

```
if let
    hashtag = aString.rangeOfString("http://"),
    word = aString.rangeOfString("95", range: hashtag.startIndex..<aString.endIndex)
{
    let hashtagWord = aString[hashtag.startIndex..<word.endIndex]
    print(hashtagWord) //->http://www.corpbpl.com/groupinfo.php?show=95
}
```

In Swift 3:

```
if
    let hashtag = aString.range(of: "http://"),
    let word = aString.range(of: "95", range: hashtag.lowerBound..<aString.endIndex)
{
    let hashtagWord = aString[hashtag.lowerBound..<word.upperBound]
    print(hashtagWord) //->http://www.corpbpl.com/groupinfo.php?show=95
}
```

Some points: (using Swift 2 terminology)

- The `rangeOfString(_:)` method of Swift String returns `Range<String.Index>`, not `NSRange`.
  You cannot assign the result into a variable of `NSRange`.
- The `startIndex` of the returned `Range` points to the first character found, the `endIndex` of the returned `Range` points to the next to the last character found.
- The `rangeOfString(_:options:range:locale:)` method (seemingly `rangeOfString(_:range:)` in the code above) is better for searching a string within some limited range, than creating a substring.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
   let aString: String = "href=http://www.corpbpl.com/groupinfo.php?show=95 onmousedown=uaction(this,{up:'90de%=%Nofi7rO6B&l=8upb1p&E%=6&ex=jXTDh5zYQLa9&});"

    var arr = aString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    let newStr = arr[0] as String

    var resultStr = newStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("href=", withString: "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.x

```
var aString = "href=http://www.corpbpl.com/groupinfo.php?show=95 onmousedown=uaction(this,{up:'90de%=%Nofi7rO6B&l=8upb1p&E%=6&ex=jXTDh5zYQLa9&});"

var hashtag = aString.rangeOfString("http://")
var word = aString.rangeOfString("95")
var hashtagWord = aString.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: hashtag!.startIndex.advancedBy(0), end: word!.endIndex.advancedBy(0)))
print(hashtagWord)
```

Output :

```
http://corbpl.com/groupinfo.php?show=95
```