# How to get a substring from a specific character to the end of the string in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a string containing a path to an image file like so:

```
/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/Hidden/data/Containers/Data/Application/Hidden/Documents/AppName/2017-07-07_21:14:52_0.jpeg
```

I'm trying to retrieve the full name of my image file like so: `2017-07-07_21:14:52_0.jpeg`

How would I get the substring starting after the last `/` to the end of the file path?

I've seen questions related to using substrings:

1. [Swift: How to get substring from start to last index of character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182441/swift-how-to-get-substring-from-start-to-last-index-of-character)
2. [How does String substring work in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift-3)
3. [Substring from String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743960/substring-from-string-in-swift)

However, the provided answers did not help me with my specific problem.

I'm sure it may be something very simple, but all I keep getting is the wrong range of substrings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your direct question: You can search for the last
occurrence of a string and get the substring from that position:

```
let path = "/Users/user/.../AppName/2017-07-07_21:14:52_0.jpeg"
if let r = path.range(of: "/", options: .backwards) {
    let imageName = String(path[r.upperBound...])
    print(imageName)  // 2017-07-07_21:14:52_0.jpeg
}
```

(Code updated for Swift 4 and later.)

But what you *really* want is the "last path component" of a file path.
`URL` has the appropriate method for that purpose:

```
let path = "/Users/user/.../AppName/2017-07-07_21:14:52_0.jpeg"
let imageName = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).lastPathComponent
print(imageName) // 2017-07-07_21:14:52_0.jpeg
```

Comment: perfect, I didn't realize `URL` had a method to serve that purpose!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

1)

```
var str = "/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/Hidden/data/Containers/Data/Application/Hidden/Documents/AppName/2017-07-07_21:14:52_0.jpeg"
let array = str.components(separatedBy: "/")

print(array[array.count-1])    //2017-07-07_21:14:52_0.jpeg
```

2)

```
let str = "/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/Hidden/data/Containers/Data/Application/Hidden/Documents/AppName/2017-07-07_21:14:52_0.jpeg"

var fileName = URL(fileURLWithPath: str).lastPathComponent

print(fileName) //2017-07-07_21:14:52_0.jpeg

let fileName = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
print(fileName) //2017-07-07_21:14:52_0
```