# How to get All the characters before a specific character while starting from the last index in Swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, string, substring

I have checked all the posts regarding string and substrings but I can't find any solution for my problem. Say I have a string "ABCD/EFG" Or "A/Ef". Now I want to get all the characters after "/" and I want to do it by only start reading from the last index. (Output: "EFG", "Ef"). Thanks

Comment: You mean all the characters _after_ "/"? (your question is quite confusing, you say "before" and the output is the last component)

Comment: Yes. I am saying 'before' as if we start reading from the last index, then when we read character ''/', then I want all the characters before it.

Comment: Like, In 1st example, I ll start reading from G, then F, then E and when I ll read '/' , I want to display EFG

Comment: You're overthinking your problem. `yourString.split(separator: "/").last` is all you need. This produces an optional string, as there's no guarantee the splitted string array contains anything.

Comment: Sorry if I forgot to mention that the string I am dealing with looks like this. 'Hotel/IsgxhSnhSSXjHvcseRrVOqseyvo1/IsgxhSnhSSXjHvcseRrVOqseyvo1Hotel/Hotel12'. So split cant be applied I think

Comment: @FahadAli Why not... works just fine

Comment: It can be aplied, it only produces an array with more than 1 result: ["Hotel", "IsgxhSnhSSXjHvcseRrVOqseyvo1", ... , "Hotel12"]. It looks like this is some sort of url however, you might want to go with the URL approach suggested by @Alladinian

Comment: The string mentioned above has the last part Hotel12. I just want to take that out. And also, that last part can change like some strings can have Room12 instead. Also, from the beginning, the String length can be varied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String `lastIndex(of:)` method to find the last occurrence of your slash character, get the index after that index limited by the string endIndex and get the substring from that index forward:

```
let str = "ABCD/EFG"
if let lastIndex = str.lastIndex(of: "/"),
    let index = str.index(lastIndex, offsetBy: 1, limitedBy: str.endIndex) {
    let substring = str[index...]  // "EFG"
    // if you need a string
    let string = String(str[index...])  // "EFG"
}
```

or as suggested by @MartinR using string `range(of:)` (this needs Foundation framework):

```
if let index = str.range(of: "/", options: .backwards)?.upperBound {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: With `range(of:)` you save the index correction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44982892/1187415 :)

Comment: @MartinR yes I didn't think about using `range(of:)` but thats definitely an option

Comment: At first, URL worked for me, but my string was not a URL and contained some spaces due to which the URL solution wasn't working. This one is working great according to my requirment.

Comment: @FahadAli: Spaces should not be a problem if you use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`

Answer (score 0):

You got a few options:

1. Split on "/" and keep the last component:

```
let text = "ABCD/EFG"

if text.contains("/"), let last = text.components(separatedBy: "/").last {
    print(last) // => EFG
}
```

2. If your strings are URLs (or have similar structure) you can make `URL` do it for you:

```
let text = "A/Ef"

if text.contains("/"), let last = URL(string: text)?.lastPathComponent {
    print(last) // => Ef
}
```

**Note**: I'm only checking for "/" presence to avoid returning matches on strings that don't have a slash. If you are parsing URLs then you probably do not need this check.